# Making activity_main-small is not working properly

Tags: android, screen

I read that to support different screen sizes you have to make a new layout (with the same name) for the different screen sizes (small, large, xlarge, normal).
Im trying to start with the small one but for some reason whenever I create it, the preview gives me Wear Square screen (a squared screen) and I can't change it to a small screen (as shown in the picture)[image: A small size layout was made]

[image: I made the layout like this]

What can be done for this to support a small screen sizes and a large ones?

Comment: For most of the screen related problems you can avoid using fixed values for layouts heights and width and use "match_parent", "wrap_contet" or "fill_parent". It solves 80 percent of the problems.

Comment: Alternatively I would suggest using **Constraint Layouts**. It ties things to one another and by using the `match_parent` / `wrap_content` layout_width and height you would not have the problem of making multiple layouts

Comment: @Sphinx I am using only Constrain Layouts but some stuff are not looking good in small screens so I cant get the desired results

Answer (score 0):

Possibly you even do not have such `small` device to see your layout in action.
The one you select on screenshots is watches - they should apply another suffixes.
Like a alternative way - try to use `percentage` attributes in `ContraintLayout` and `autoSize` attributes for `TextView`.